# How to get the word tapped on in a UILabel

Tags: ios

In an app I'm writing I think it would be best if the user can tap on a UILabel and I can see what word they tapped on.  Is there anyway I can do this?

Comment: I think you can add UIGesturesRecognize to your UILabel.  Look up UIGestureRecognizer..

Comment: Why not just use `UITextfield`? it looks like the `UILabel` & can accept words the user tapped in.

Comment: I don't really want the user to be able to edit the field.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can do it use a **UIWebview**

use

```
- (void)loadHTMLString:(NSString *)string baseURL:(NSURL *)baseURL;
```

and code the whole message then wrap the link to

```
[webView.loadHTMLString:@"<a href="tap:Google">Google</a>" baseURL:nil];
```

then in the delegate method

```
- (BOOL)webView:(UIWebView *)webView shouldStartLoadWithRequest:(NSURLRequest *)request navigationType:(UIWebViewNavigationType)navigationType
```

you will know which word you tapped

```
   if ( [request.URL.scheme compare:FeverProtocolIdentifier] == NSOrderedSame ) 
    {    
        NSString *word = request.URL.resourceSpecifier;
    }
```

Comment: i vae my uilabel is in tableviewcell.  How can i do this

Answer (score 1):

I don't think this is very easy. I would probably use an [OHAttributedLabel](https://github.com/AliSoftware/OHAttributedLabel) rather than a UILabel and add a method to the OHAttributedLabel code to return the information you need. If you look at the linkAtPoint method in [OHAttributedLabel.m](https://github.com/AliSoftware/OHAttributedLabel/blob/master/OHAttributedLabel.m), you can see what you'll need to do. I would duplicate that method, naming the new one **characterOffsetAtPoint** perhaps, and then return the index that the existing code calculates at line 340.