# Get word that was tapped in UILabel instead of character [iOS]

Tags: ios, string

I am trying to extract the word that was tapped in a UILabel using tap gesture recognizer.  I am able to get the character that was tapped, as well as the range of the character, but I am not able to extract the full word.  Is there a way to get the full string of the word that was tapped instead of the character?

```
 if let label = descriptionLabel, tapGestureRecognizer != nil {
    if label.attributedText == nil {
        return
    }
    let storage = NSTextStorage(attributedString: label.attributedText ?? NSAttributedString())
    let textContainer = NSTextContainer(size: label.bounds.size)
    let layoutManager = NSLayoutManager()
    layoutManager.addTextContainer(textContainer)
    storage.addLayoutManager(layoutManager)
    textContainer.lineFragmentPadding = 0.0
    textContainer.lineBreakMode = (label.lineBreakMode)
    textContainer.maximumNumberOfLines = label.numberOfLines
    let location: CGPoint = tapGestureRecognizer!.location(in: label)
    let characterIndex: Int = layoutManager.characterIndex(for: location, in: textContainer, fractionOfDistanceBetweenInsertionPoints: nil)

    if characterIndex < storage.length {
        print("Character Index: \(Int(characterIndex))")
        let range = NSRange(location: characterIndex, length: 1)
        let substring: String? = (label.attributedText?.string as NSString?)?.substring(with: range)

        //prints out one character, how do I get the full word of this character
        print(substring)          
    }
}
```

Much appreciated

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to get the word tapped on in a UILabel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10201941/how-to-get-the-word-tapped-on-in-a-uilabel)

Comment: I do not want to use a webview

Comment: You can calculate the word being pressed from the index.

Answer (score 0):

I don't like this way, but it works.  Place the following after the   print(substring) statement.  Why doesn't UIKit have a method to extract the full string at a Range?  Ridiculous.

```
let afterWords: [Any] = (afterString.components(separatedBy: " "))
let beforeWords: [Any] = (beforeString.components(separatedBy: ", "))

var attachmentString = ""
if let stringBeforeLocation = beforeWords.last as? String, let stringAfterLocation = afterWords.first as? String {

    attachmentString = stringBeforeLocation
    if stringAfterLocation.count > 0 {
        let choppedString = (stringAfterLocation as NSString).substring(from: 1)
        attachmentString = attachmentString + choppedString
        print("FULL STRING TAPPED \(attachmentString)")
    }
}
```